# Binary search tree recursive destructor

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, destructor

I have checked other similar topics, but none seemed to help me.

I am trying to write a destructor for this specific BST implementation. Every node contains a pointer to the parent, a pointer to the left node, a pointer to the right node and a pointer to the value it contains.
This is how the beginning of the class looks:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class BST{
    private:
        BST<T> *left;
        BST<T> *right;
        BST<T> *parent;
        T *value;

    public:
        BST() {
            this->parent = NULL;
            this->left = NULL;
            this->right = NULL;
            this->value = NULL;
        }

        ~BST() {
            removeRecursively(this);
        }

        void removeRecursively(BST<T>* node) {
            if (node->left != NULL)
                removeRecursively(node->left);
            if (node->right != NULL)
                removeRecursively(node->right);
            if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) {
                if (node->parent->left == node)
                    node->parent->left = NULL;
                if (node->parent->right == node)
                    node->parent->right = NULL;

                node->parent = NULL;
                node->value = NULL;
                delete node->value;
                delete node;
            }
        }

        void add(T value) {
            if (this->value == NULL) { // root-only case
                this->value = new T;
                *(this->value) = value;
            }
            else {
                if (value < *(this->value)) {
                    if (this->left != NULL) // has left child
                        this->left->add(value);
                    else { // has no left child
                        this->left = new BST<T>;
                        this->left->value = new T;
                        this->left->parent = this;
                        *(this->left->value) = value;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (this->right != NULL) // has right child
                        this->right->add(value);
                    else { // has no right child
                        this->right = new BST<T>;
                        this->right->value = new T;
                        this->right->parent = this;
                        *(this->right->value) = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void inOrderDisplay() {
            if (this->left != NULL)
                this->left->inOrderDisplay();
            std::cout << *(this->value) << " ";
            if (this->right != NULL)
                this->right->inOrderDisplay();
        }

        BST<T>* search(T value) {
            if (*(this->value) == value)
                return this;
            else if (this->left != NULL && value < *(this->value))
                return this->left->search(value);
            else if (this->right != NULL && value > *(this->value))
                return this->right->search(value);
            else
                return NULL;
        }

        BST<T>* remove(T value) {
            BST<T>* node = search(value);

            if (node != NULL) {
                if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) { // leaf node
                    delete node->value;
                    if (node->parent->left == node) // is left child
                        node->parent->left = NULL;
                    else // is right child
                        node->parent->right = NULL;
                    delete node;
                }

                // 1 child nodes
                if (node->left != NULL && node->right == NULL) { // has left child
                    if (node->parent->left == node) // is left child
                        node->parent->left = node->left;
                    else // is right child
                        node->parent->right = node->left;
                    delete node->value;
                    node->parent = NULL;
                    delete node;
                }

                if (node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL) { // has right child
                    if (node->parent->left == node) // is left child
                        node->parent->left = node->right;
                    else // is right child
                        node->parent->right = node->right;
                    delete node->value;
                    node->parent = NULL;
                    delete node;
                }

                // 2 children nodes
                if (node->left != NULL && node->right != NULL) {
                    T aux;
                    BST<T>* auxNode = node->right;

                    while (auxNode->left != NULL)
                    auxNode = auxNode->left;

                    aux = *(auxNode->value);

                    if (auxNode->right != NULL) {
                        *(auxNode->value) = *(auxNode->right->value);
                        auxNode->right->parent = NULL;
                        auxNode->right->value = NULL;
                        auxNode->right = NULL;
                        delete auxNode->right;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (auxNode->parent->left == auxNode) // is left child
                            auxNode->parent->left = NULL;
                        else // is right child
                            auxNode->parent->right = NULL;
                        auxNode->value = NULL;
                        delete auxNode;
                    }
                    *(node->value) = aux; 
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
};
#endif // BST_H
```

The BST class is used as below:

```
BST<int>* root = new BST<int>();

root->add(5);
root->add(2);
root->add(-17);

root->inOrderDisplay();

root->remove(5);
```

I mention that all the methods work properly (I decided not to post them,  since they are not the subject of this question). The problem is that when I run my test file with Valgrind, it detects some memory leaks and I am sure that they occur because of the lack of a proper destructor (the above one produces a segmentation fault).

*EDIT:* I added the code for the other methods

Thank you!

Comment: You should include your code for `add` (and `remove`) ... you could be making a mistake in those ...

Comment: Use RAII: `std::unique_ptr<BST<T>> left; std::unique_ptr<BST<T>> right; std::unique_ptr<T> value; BST<T>* parent;`

Comment: I looked at it twice, but I can't find anything wrong with your `removeRecursively()`, although I think nulling your pointers is not necessary. But it won't harm either.

Comment: *i mention that all the methods work properly* -- If I had a dollar for every time I hear this where the code not posted **is** the problem, I would be a rich man.  You posted a call to the `add` function in the `main` program.  You post, we need to see.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: There are several problem in `removeRecursively()` including (but not only) those pointed in current answers.

Comment: @Jarod24: you are right. I would not null at all (the object is about to disappear anyway), so I disregarded that.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Copying and pasting your code in Visual Studio and running it under the debugger instantly takes you to where the issue is in the `remove` function:  `node->parent->left`  -- `node->parent` is a NULL pointer.  Now how to fix it -- review your plan you had in mind, make the requisite changes, and debug your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic design is kind of broken, at least IMO. That is, if you're willing to jump through enough hoops, you can probably make it work, but even at best it'll probably always be at least a little clumsy to work with.

I'd start by defining a separate class for the nodes in the tree. Then the tree itself will hold a pointer to the root of the tree and define most of the interface to the tree.

```
template <class T>
class Tree {

    struct node {
        node *parent;
        node *left;
        node *right;
        T *value;

        node(T *value) 
            : parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), value(new T(value))
        {             
        }

        ~node() { 
            delete(left);
            delete(right);
            delete(value);
        }           
    } *root;

    Tree() : root(nullptr) {}

    ~Tree() { 
        delete(root);
    }
};
```

Destruction doesn't have to be explicitly recursive. The `delete(left)` (for example) will invoke the dtor for the left child node (if there is one) and that'll invoke the dtor for its child nodes, and so on. When we reach a leaf node, we'll end up with (the equivalent of) `delete nullptr;`, which is defined as doing nothing, stopping the recursion.

Comment: That's a comprehensive design.

Answer (score 2):

You should swap the lines:

```
            node->value = NULL;
            delete node->value;
```

Like this:

```
            delete node->value;
            node->value = NULL;
```

if you first assign `NULL` you delete nothing.

Comment: I tried it but the destructor is still causing the segfault.

Comment: @Polb where exactly? You may have **another** problem

Comment: Using the empty destructor makes my code run fine, no segfault, but 400 KB of memory leak. Perhaps the destructor implementation I wrote is not good at all.

Comment: @Polb You should add all your code and give the exact error and where it occurred

Comment: There is no need to NULL at all, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest bugs to find are the ones in the code you've decided not to look at because you've convinced yourself they're not relevant.

Anyways, there is one evident problem with your implementation: after removing a bunch of other stuff, you are basically doing

```
class foo
{
    ~foo() { delete this; }
};
```

Comment: If using an empty destructor, the BST works as expected, however the problem is the memory leak.

Comment: I believe he's pointing out that if the destructor for that node is being called, something is already deleting it. Hence you're deleting the node twice.

Comment: Using `delete this` also doesn't work so well if the object is allocated on the stack, or as a global or static.

Answer (score 1):

Use RAII with `unique_ptr` to avoid those issues:

```
template <typename T>
class BST{
public:
    BST() = default;
    ~BST() = default;

    BST(const BST&) = delete;
    BST& operator =(const BST&) = delete;
    BST(BST&&) = delete;
    BST& operator =(BST&&) = delete;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<BST<T>> left;
    std::unique_ptr<BST<T>> right;
    BST<T>* parent = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<T> value;
};
```